# Applying styles as StaticResource inside nested style

Tags: wpf

I have a styles.xaml file that merges in a bunch of color definitions:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

If I reference those colors from my styles.xaml as a `StaticResource`, they work fine, so this works:

```
<Style x:Key="Timestamp" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource LightTextColorBrush}"/>
</Style>
```

However if I try to reference those colors from a style that contains a nested style, it doesn't work, and is ignored:

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="FollowOnChatUserItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource LightTextColorBrush}"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Here, I am saying that all TextBlocks within my StackPanel style should use that color, but it doesn't work. If I change the `Value="{StaticResource LightTextColorBrush}"` to something like `Orange` that does work.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Fixed it thanks to responses below..

I've adding My Resources to App.xaml instead of the Window.xaml that was using them, so my App.xaml contains:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I've removed the merge from my window.xaml, and I've changed from `StaticResource` to `DynamicResource` and it works

Comment: I believe the problem is that the merged dictionary resources aren't in the resource tree of of the controls that the style is being applied to during loading. You need to merge your resource dictionaries in App.xaml, or at least in the control template xaml files.

Comment: Matt, Is the style being applied to an element defined in a control template, in a separate file?

Comment: Michael, thanks, you and Nitesh were correct - I was hasty with my initial "not working" - it was in fact the right solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set as DynamicResource instead of StaticResource and merge Styles.xaml to the App.xaml.

Comment: That's not making any difference

Comment: I merge colors.xaml into styles.xaml in styles.xaml, and that gets merged into my MainWindow.xaml (not app.xaml)

Comment: That is ok if you have put your color resources in Styles.xaml. Have you added this Styles.xaml in the App.xaml ?

Comment: Please merge Styles.xaml in App.xaml and then see if it works.

Comment: No - it's just added into the window directly that I'm using it in... I add it to MainWindow.xaml - I'll try adding to app.xaml as you suggest

Comment: Thanks, that's sorted it.